# Show NaN rows in a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, nan

I would like to print all NaN rows in `df`:

`df`:

```
from pandas import *
from numpy import *

df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp': {383439: Timestamp('2000-10-26 23:37:43.880000'),
  304351: Timestamp('2000-10-26 23:37:52.880000'),
  311295: Timestamp('2000-10-26 23:38:18.880000'),
  358356: Timestamp('2000-10-26 23:38:21.880000'),
  313155: Timestamp('2000-10-26 23:38:22.450000'),
  372410: Timestamp('2000-10-26 23:38:27.450000'),
  336183: Timestamp('2000-10-27 05:42:32.960000'),
  321794: Timestamp('2000-10-27 05:42:47.960000'),
  297537: Timestamp('2000-10-27 22:54:11.880000'),
  346700: Timestamp('2000-10-27 22:54:14.880000')},
 'Flag': {383439: 1.0,
  304351: 0.0,
  311295: 1.0,
  358356: nan,
  313155: 1.0,
  372410: 0.0,
  336183: nan,
  321794: nan,
  297537: 1.0,
  346700: 0.0},
 'Value': {383439: nan,
  304351: 1,
  311295: 0,
  358356: nan,
  313155: 1,
  372410: nan,
  336183: 1,
  321794: 0,
  297537: nan,
  346700: nan},
 'Number': {383439: 0,
  304351: 0,
  311295: 0,
  358356: 0,
  313155: 0,
  372410: 0,
  336183: 0,
  321794: 0,
  297537: 0,
  346700: 0},
 'Id': {383439: 30,
  304351: 30,
  311295: 30,
  358356: 30,
  313155: 30,
  372410: 2,
  336183: 2,
  321794: 2,
  297537: 2,
  346700: 2},
  })
```

I used:

```
df[df.isna()]
```

which returned

```
       Timestamp    Flag    Value   Number  Id
383439  NaT         NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
304351  NaT         NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
311295  NaT         NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
358356  NaT         NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
313155  NaT         NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
372410  NaT         NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
336183  NaT         NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
321794  NaT         NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
297537  NaT         NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
346700  NaT         NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

What is `df[df.isna()]` doing and what's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We check for row so we need add `any`

```
dfx[dfx.isna().any(1)]
Out[212]: 
                     Timestamp  Flag  Value  Number  Id
383439 2000-10-26 23:37:43.880   1.0    NaN       0  30
358356 2000-10-26 23:38:21.880   NaN    NaN       0  30
372410 2000-10-26 23:38:27.450   0.0    NaN       0   2
336183 2000-10-27 05:42:32.960   NaN    1.0       0   2
321794 2000-10-27 05:42:47.960   NaN    0.0       0   2
297537 2000-10-27 22:54:11.880   1.0    NaN       0   2
346700 2000-10-27 22:54:14.880   0.0    NaN       0   2
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. What's does `df[df.isna()]` do though?

Comment: only select value by isna return True , which is NaN as well, and mask all other False to NaN @nilsinelabore

Comment: @nilsinelabore also simple try dfx[dfx==0], you will find it ~